# Change image size on Bee3D slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I used Bee3d library on this link from Github

https://github.com/lukeed/bee3d

Everything is really amazing but
I'm wondering if there is option to change image size,
because when I change image size in CSS there make a big space between images

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the slide side by editing `src/styles/_config.sass` variables named `$slide-w` and `$slide-h`

From github issue: https://github.com/lukeed/bee3d/issues/18